# Why sin(45) appears in the eigenvectors of a matrix of all one's

Tags: trigonometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Take the following matrix:

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Each cell of its normalized eigenvectors is either positive or negative $\sin 45$. Why does this happen?

Comment: Well...what are the nullspace and column space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ is an eigenvector then so is $cx$ for any nonzero scalar $c$.

This matrix maps the vector $x = (1,1)$ to $(2,2)$, which means that $2$ is an eigenvalue with corresponding eigenvector $(1,1)$. The length of $(1,1)$ is $\sqrt{2}$, so we can choose $c = 1/\sqrt{2}$ to obtain a normalized (unit length) eigenvector $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$, and $1/\sqrt{2}$ happens to equal the cosine (and the sine) of 45 degrees.

Similarly, the matrix maps $(1,-1)$ to $(0,0)$, which means that $0$ is an eigenvalue with corresponding eigenvector $(1,-1)$, which we can normalize to $(1/\sqrt{2}, -1/\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: The eigenvectors in my question were normalized, this this makes sense. This pattern should continue to higher dimensions, so if the length of each eigenvector is 3, and they contain only one's, each value will be $1/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @pengowen123 That's correct. Note, normalization is completely optional. $(1,1)$ is just as valid an eigenvector as $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$. Software packages such as Matlab will often normalize for convenience and/or as a side effect of how the eigenvectors were computed. Also, even if you normalize, you have a choice of signs. In this example, $(-1/\sqrt{2}, -1/\sqrt{2})$ is also a normalized eigenvector, obtained by taking $c = -1/\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
fixes every vector, while
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
reflects every vector in the line through the origin with gradient $1$, so it fixes $(1,1)$ and reverses the sense of $(1,-1)$ to $(-1,1)$, since $(1,-1)$ is orthogonal to $(1,1)$.

It follows that your matrix, being the sum of these two matrices, takes $\sqrt{2}(\sin 60, \sin 60)=(1,1)$ to 
$$(1,1)+(1,1)=(2,2)=2\sqrt{2}(\sin 60, \sin 60),$$ and takes $\sqrt{2}(\sin 60, -\sin 60)=(1,-1)$ to
$$(1,-1)+(-1,1)=(0,0)=0(\sin 60, -\sin 60).$$